Compressed image using SVD draws a clear line between part that's blank and part with a drawing. Why?
I'm trying to compress grayscale images using SVD. This is the original image:

Yes, there's a lot of blank space.
I then choose the x% largest singular values, perform the transformed matrices multiplications and visualise the transformed image.
These are the results:



(This is using the first 5%, 15% and 30% largest singular values, respectively.)
Now, why is there such a clearly drawn line between the lower and the upper part of the image? It doesn't make sense to me why the blanks of the lower part of the figure are filled with noise while the upper part is kept intact. It also seems suggestive that there's a strip in the lower right that's filled with less noise than its left.
Why does this happen? By compressing an image, I would expect it to be just blurred, but the appearance of what seems to be random noise in the blanks is puzzling me.

Try to ask this question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

It makes complete sense that lines of zero values are left out of the reduced sum and thus retain their zero value. You could try to base the SVD on the columns of the image.
